# Return by reference or create a typical setter/getter?

Tags: c++

I was wondering about good practices in C++, and I was facing the problem of making a getter/setter for a class member.

So, why don't simply return the member by reference so this way I can modify or access its value to read it? Specifically, this is my code:

```
class Chest : public GameObject
{
public:
    Chest();
    ~Chest();

    static int& num_chests();

private:
    static int num_chests_;
};
```

Is this a bad practice? Should I use these instead?

```
class Chest : public GameObject
{
public:
    Chest();
    ~Chest();

    static int num_chests();
    static void set_num_chests(int num_chests);

private:
    static int num_chests_;
};
```

Comment: If the getter doesn't do anything, and the setter doesn't do anything, then BOTH are wrong.  Make `num_chests_` public.  Otherwise, the second is required.  It's incredibly rare to return a member by reference.

Comment: Or you could go with option 3 and make `num_chests` a `public` data member, especially if your setter doesn't need to do any validation tests.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly bad practice. It's a common idiom in C++ to use/return references.

Comment: Do you have currently a constraint or precondition you want to enforce for num_chests_? If so, use setters and getters; otherwise make it a public member.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's highly uncommon to return a _member_ by reference.  Commonly member functions return `*this` by reference.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was refusing to make variable members public since when I was studying Java my teacher in the university HATED public variables in classes.

Comment: Setters are good for validating input to a member variable. Getters are good for protecting the actual member from direct outside manipulation. If you want to directly manipulate a member and have no validation concerns, then set that member to public. Otherwise, it should be more restricted and accessor functions should be used.

Comment: @Puyover, but C++ is not Java, The C++ community understand the benefits in certain circumstances of public members. Take for example the pair class in the standard library, its interface is its public members.

Comment: @Puyover You teacher is wrong. If it was bad design to have public members, the compiler would refuse compiling it. I've been teached setters and getters for many years, and today with experience I stopped doing it systematically. The better thing to do is to THINK why it is necessary to write a setter/getter, and if you don't find any reason to do so, then it is probably not necessary.

Comment: You've stumbled onto one of those "KILL all who disagree!" topics in computer science.  This one is as bad or worse than "return codes vs exceptions" and "interfaces vs delegates".  I think only "Emacs vs Vi" has people more nuts about it.  For the languages that support it (like C#) this is the "Properties vs public field" debate.  Your question about "reference vs by value vs pointer" is usually more technical, and less "strong belief" based.

Comment: @neodelphi - The compiler does not enforce good design or style. This provides many of us with grief and employment.

Comment: In a strong object oriented design, you would use getters and setters. In a mixed or weak object oriented design, you can use public members when there is no need for validation or protection from external manipulation.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer For a second there I read that as "...grief and **enjoyment**."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you feel very strongly against it, use getter and setter member functions.

The reason `int& num_chests()` or a public field is bad is that you are coupling client code that uses the `num_chests` value to the fact that it is actually a field (an internal implementation detail).

Suppose that later you decided you would have a `std::vector<Chest> chests` private field in your class. Then you wouldn't want to have a `int num_chests` field -- it's horribly redundant. You would want to have `int num_chests() { return chests.size(); }`.

If you were using a public field, now all of your client code needs to use this function instead of the previous field access -- every usage of the `num_chests` value needs to be updated, because the interface has changed.

If you were using a function that returns a reference, you now have a problem because `chests.size()` is a return by value -- you can't in-turn return that by reference.

Always encapsulate your data. It requires only a minimal amount of boilerplate code.

In response to comments saying you should just use public fields:

Keep in mind that the *only* benefit of using public fields (other than the remote possibility of some micro-optimization) is that you don't have to write the boilerplate code.  "My teacher used to hate when I used public fields (and he was sooo annoying)" is a very poor argument for using public fields.

Comment: Can you say if you consider the pair class as a bad design?

Comment: @Rayniery No. The design there is such that, if I have a `pair<T1, T2> p`, the `p.first` and `p.second` fields actually have variable semantics as much as the variable `p` does. The interface and semantics *is* that they are variables. The `pair<T1, T2>` type (and `tuple` as well) serves as a lightweight means of tying variables (or values) together - certainly not as a tool for data encapsulation!

Answer (score 2):

In almost every case, when you think you have to create setter AND getter (that is, both at the same time), your design is wrong.

Think instead what purpose has `num_chests`? You can't go anywhere without knowing what it is.

By your code I'm guessing it contains the number of chests on the level. In that case you don't want to provide setter for this value for everyone. You want the value to be equal to the number of chests in the game, and by providing setter here everyone can invalidate that invariant.

Instead, you can provide ONLY getter, and you can control it's value in your class.

```
class Chest : public GameObject
{
public:
    Chest() { ++num_chests_; }
    ~Chest() { --num_chests_; }

    static int num_chests() { return num_chests_; }

private:
    static int num_chests_;
};

int Chest::num_chests_ = 0;
```

More explanation about why getters and setters are wrong decision in my opinion.
If you provide setter and getter, you only have illusion of control over variable. Consider `std::complex`. Why is

```
std::complex<double> my_complex(1.0, 5.0);
my_complex.real(my_complex.real()+1);
```

better over

```
std::complex<double> my_complex(1.0, 5.0);
my_complex.real()++;
```

The answer: when `std::complex` was designed, there were no references in C++. Also, Java doesn't have C++-style references, so they have to write boilerplate code everywhere. Now, GCC returns non-const references here as an extension, and C++11 allows

```
reinterpret_cast<double (&)[2]>(non_const_non_volatile_complex_variable)[0]
```

and

```
reinterpret_cast<double (&)[2]>(non_const_non_volatile_complex_variable)[1]
```

as a valid way to access real and imaginary parts of `std::complex<value>`.

Comment: I like your answer. You motivate to think about the purpose of the member instead of saying to do always this or that. I think that is one of the main problems of software design: we are so used to "recipes" that tell us to do one thing instead of motivate us to think about the particularities of the design and domain at hand.

Comment: "Every time you think you have to create setter AND getter (that is, both at the same time), your design is wrong." - It may be a bit too strong to say it's "wrong"... It's definitely a reason to double check your design, but there are legitimate cases for having a getter and setter.

Comment: @TimothyShields Of course, there is no silver bullet in programming, but most of the time, it's design failure.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of your interface is *not* to be the simplest to **program**, but the simplest to **use** and **extend**.

If you fail to provide setter and getter methods, you are setting yourself up for later headaches. For example:

- what happens if you need to emit a notification whenever someone changes the value of `num_chests`?
- what happens if you need to validate than `num_chests` cannot be negative?
- what happens if you need to run the program in a multi-thread environment and need to lock the reads until the writes are ready?

As you can see, an interface that is transparent to the user is also simpler to protect against user errors, and also extend in the future; this advantage comes at very little (if any) extra cost.

On the other hand, sometimes you do want to return a reference or pointer to an internal member. For example, the container classes in the Standard Library often offer a `data()` method that retrieves a pointer to the underlying container (both in the `const` and non-`const` variations).

So, it is not a hard rule, but I would say that returning non-const references to private members defeats the purpose of OO programming.

Answer (score 0):

I aim for low coupling and high cohesion; I avoid getters and setters.

If you have getters and setters, another object is going to have to know how to call them. That's coupling.

Try to decouple your objects but make them cohesive. By cohesion I mean they work well with the rest of the system.

What is your system? Why do you have getters and setters? Because you want to control and display these objects. They are the model and you have controllers and views on them.

It's easy to fall into the trap of having coupling between your control/view and your model.

To avoid coupling, let the model create the control and update the view. Then it won't have to have any getters or setters.

e.g.

```
struct Instrumenter {
    virtual void addRange(int& value, int min, int max) = 0;
};

struct Renderer {
    virtual void render(std::string& description, int value) = 0;
};

struct GameObject {
    virtual void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) = 0;
    virtual void display(Renderer& renderer) = 0;
};

struct Chest : GameObject {
    virtual void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) {
        intrumenter.addRange(count, 0, 10);
    }
    virtual void display(Renderer& renderer) {
        renderer.render("Chest count", count);
    }
private:
    int count;
};
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
int main() {
    vector<shared_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;
    MyControlInstrumenter instrumenter;
    // ...
    for(auto& gameObject: gameObjects) {
        gameObject->instrument(instrumenter);
    }
    // etc.
}
```